# Try to prove a generalization of the IVT?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is the statement :

"Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function on $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ and $a,b \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Then for all $u \in \left(\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x), \lim \limits_{x\to b} f(x) \right)$ or $u \in \left(\lim \limits_{x\to b} f(x), \lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x) \right)$ (with $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x) \ne \lim \limits_{x\to b} f(x)$) there is $k \in (a,b)$ such that $f(k) = u$."

So we have three main cases :

- Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x)= \pm \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to b} f(x)= \pm \infty$.
- Let $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$ with $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} f(x)= c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= d\in \mathbb{R}$.
- Let $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$ with $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} f(x)= \pm \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= \pm \infty$.

I tried to prove the first case. I want to apply the initial theorem which only works for compact interval.

WLOG, I suppose that : $\lim \limits_{x\to a} f(x)= - \infty$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to b}(x)= + \infty$

Writing the definition of limits I obtain :

$\forall A \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \eta_1>0, \forall x \in (a,b), \mid x-a\mid \le \eta_1 \Rightarrow f(x) \le A$.
$\forall B \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \eta_2>0, \forall x \in (a,b), \mid x-b\mid \le \eta_2 \Rightarrow f(x) \ge B$.

Then for $k \in (a,b)$, I can chose $\eta_3 = \min\{\eta_1, \eta_2\}>0$ such as for $x\in [k-\eta_3, k+ \eta_3]$ I have $f(x) \in [B,A]$.

Does that imply that I can apply the usual theorem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $A$ should be allowed to be negative. However, I don't get your proof.

Comment: You should consider $A = u-1$, $B = u+1$, and $[a+\eta_1, b-\eta_2]$, if you want to reduce the claim to the standard IVT.

Comment: From a topological point of view, the intermediate value theorem says that the image of a connected set under a continuous mapping is connected. Once you exclude the cases where the limits in the statement of your question don't exist, this should answer your question (the connected subsets of the extended real line are the intervals).

Comment: @RobArthan I already know the topological argument but I want to write it with the limits

Comment: @user251257 What's the problem with the interval $[k-\eta_3,k+\eta_3]$ ?

Comment: So if you know how to prove this already, what is your question?

Comment: the singularities are at $a$ and $b$ not at $k$ :)

Comment: @RobArthan I have to explain to a friend who doesn't have any knowledge in topology

Comment: OK: so you have lots of cases to enumerate, but the topological proof will tell you what to do in each case. Do note that you must exclude the cases where the limits don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = +\infty$:

There exists some $\eta > 0$ such that for all $x\in(a,b)$ we have:

1. If $x - a < \eta$, then $f(x) < u - 1$.
2. If $b - x < \eta$, then $f(x) > u + 1$.

By continuity, we have $f(a + \eta) \le u - 1 < u + 1 \le f(b - \eta)$.
Thus, by IVT for bounded closed interval, there exists some $k\in(a+\eta, b-\eta)$ with $f(k) = u$.

All other cases are analogue.

Comment: Thanks, we must have $k \in [a+\eta,b-\eta]$ ?

Comment: @Maman: such a $k$ surely exists. There might also be one in $(a, a+\eta)$. But that's not important, right?

Comment: Just to be more precise, then with this method we have $f(k) \in [u-1,u+1]$

Comment: @Maman: The proof shows, there is some $k\in(a+\eta, b-\eta)$ with $f(k) = u$.

Comment: Ok but one thing why it is the same $\eta$ ?

Comment: @Maman: You could use a $\eta_1$ for $a$ and $\eta_2$ for $b$. However, you can always choose $\eta=\min(\eta_1, \eta_2)$. I was just lazy to distinguish them.

Comment: I see and what was the problem with $[B,A]$ ? $u$ is not necessary in it ?

Comment: @Maman In your proof, $B$ should be intuitively large, near $+\infty$, and $A$ should be small, near $-\infty$. You ordered them wrong. And you have not assumed that $u$ is in $[A,B]$.

Comment: Thanks not easy when you cannot apply directly the theorem...

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't need to consider so many cases. Just two cases are sufficient.

**Case 1)** $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) < u < \lim_{x \to b}f(x)$. Then it is obvious that there exist real numbers $A, B$ with $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) < A < u < B < \lim_{x \to b}f(x)$$ and by definition of limits we can see that there is a value of $x$ near $a$ and greater than $a$ (call it $c$) such that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) < f(c) < A$ and similarly there is a $d$ such that $d < b$ and $B < f(d) < \lim_{x \to b}f(x)$. Also since $a < b$ we can choose $c, d$ such that $c < d$. We thus have real numbers $c, d$ with $c < d$ and $f(c) < A < u < B < f(d)$. Applying IVT on closed interval $[c, d]$ we get the existence of a number $k \in (c, d)$ with $f(k) = u$.

**Case 2)** $\lim_{x \to b}f(x) < u < \lim_{x \to a}f(x)$. This can be done exactly in same manner as case 1) with obvious minor modifications.

**Note**: There is an assumption that the limits $\lim_{x \to a}f(x), \lim_{x \to b}f(x)$ belong to extended real number system $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ which includes $\pm\infty$ also (in the same manner in which both $a, b$ belong to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$).